# Binding cell properties to DataBoundItem

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, datagridview

I'm setting some properties of [`DataGridViewCell`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewcell(v=vs.110).aspx) based on values stored [`DataGridViewRow.DataBoundItem`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewrow.databounditem(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp#code-snippet-1), for example:

```
DataGridViewRow row;
MyObject obj = row.DataBoundItem as MyObject;
row.Cells["MyCell"].ReadOnly = !obj.CanBeEdited;
```

Right now I'm *abusing* [`RowPrePaint`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.onrowprepaint(v=vs.110).aspx) event to set these up, but the problem is that objects displayed in the datagrid are being changed from another thread, and I need those properties set correctly without redrawing (for example selecting multiple screens of rows and editing multiple values).

**Q:** What is the proper way of binding properties DataBoundItems to Cell properties?

Is there some method (like [`DataGridView.InvalidateRow`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridview.invalidaterow(v=vs.110).aspx)) where functionality like this *should* be implemented?

Comment: try set `row.Cells["MyCell"].ReadOnly` in grid `CellEnter` event handler: you will enable or disable edit just before someone started editing

Comment: @ASh I provide pop up for the user to fill comment on each element and works like `foreach(row in dgv.SelectedRows){if(row.Cells["Comment"].ReadOnly){continue;} ... }`

Comment: cell.ReadOnly enables/disables edit for that cell. i don't see why do you need it for smth else. as for you snippet: `foreach(DataGridViewRow row in dgv.SelectedRows){ MyObject obj = row.DataBoundItem as MyObject; if(!obj.CanBeEdited) {continue;} ... }` probably

Comment: @Vyktor Are you trying to make certain rows `ReadOnly` based on the `.CanBeEdited` property in your `DataBoundItem`?

Comment: @jaredbaszler certain cells, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible solutions.  I didn't compile any of this code but it should be pretty close to working if it doesn't compile for some reason.

**#1**

Hook into the `CellEnter` event and set the cell's `ReadOnly` property to your  `CanBeEdited` property at that time.  Such as:

```
void dataGrid_CellEnter(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
{
    var obj = dataGrid.Rows[e.RowIndex].DataBoundItem;
    dataGrid.CurrentRow.Cells[e.ColumnIndex].ReadOnly = !obj.CanBeEdited;
}
```

**#2**

If for some reason that won't work your only other option will be to loop through all rows and columns after the data is loaded and set the `ReadOnly` property that way.  You could run this code in the `DataBindingComplete` event of your datagrid.  But, if your data changes a lot this code is not efficient so that may slow things down.  If your data only loads once, this snippet of code should work fine for you.

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGrid.Rows)
{
    if ((row.Index == -1) || (e.RowIndex == dataGrid.NewRowIndex))
    {
        continue; // disregard row headers and also the new row
    }

    var obj = row.DataBoundItem;

    foreach (DataGridViewColumn col in row.Cells)
    {
         if (col.Index == -1)
         {
              continue; // disregard column headers
         }

         col.ReadOnly = !obj.CanBeEdited
    }
}
```